# Using dynamic in CellPrint/Cell to get an "Item"?

Tags: dynamic

When using stuff like:

```
CellPrint[Cell["Z/" <> ToString[Prime[n]] <> "Z", "Item"]]
```

How can I use dynamic functionality in there? I was planning to create a dynamic variable n and make it dynamic in there but it's not working. I tried using the following slider:

```
{Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, 100, 1}], Dynamic[n]}
```

And the following codes:

```
CellPrint[Cell["Z/" <> ToString[Prime[Dynamic[n]]] <> "Z", "Item"]]
```

And

```
CellPrint[Cell["Z/" <> ToString[Evaluate[Prime[Refresh[n, UpdateInterval -> 1]]]] <> "Z", "Item"]]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you need to use CellPrint instead of Print, and why can't you use Row instead of creating a string?

Comment: @CarlWoll Print outputs [this](https://i.imgur.com/bKJDkLZ.png).

Comment: So, don't use a Cell wrapper

Comment: @CarlWoll I need it to create an "Item" with an `n` that updates dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?:

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Row[{"Z/",Dynamic[Prime@n],"Z"}],"Item"]];
Slider[Dynamic@n,{1,10,1}]
```

Or perhaps:

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[
   Row[{"Z/", Dynamic[Prime@n], "Z"}],
   "Item",
   ShowStringCharacters -> False]];
```

Comment: I need it to output an `"Item"`.

Comment: @RedBanana Do you mean instead of `”Output”`? Do you mean you can’t make that change yourself?

Comment: @RedBanana Sorry, I was on an iOS device and couldn’t read the question and enter an answer at the same time. — Oops, battery is dying, now, too. :)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much!